# Как очистить данные с pictureBox? c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть код, который при нажатии на кнопку печатает заданный текст на картинку, но если напечатать еще раз не перезагружая программу, то все происходит на поверхности созданного же изображение. Вопрос в следующем, как исправить это или же как при нажатии на кнопку сбрасывать данные от туда? Я новичок и это моя первая программа на c#, не судите строго

```
private void bunifuButton1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image a = (pictureBox1.Image);
        Graphics part1 = Graphics.FromImage(a);       //Артикул 
        Graphics part2 = Graphics.FromImage(a);      //Цвет              
        Graphics part3 = Graphics.FromImage(a);     //Размер
        Graphics part4 = Graphics.FromImage(a);    //Состав

        part1.DrawString(bunifuTextBox1.Text,
        new System.Drawing.Font("Inconsolata", 8, FontStyle.Bold),
        new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(250, 137, 500, 500),
        new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap));

        part2.DrawString(bunifuTextBox2.Text,
        new System.Drawing.Font("Inconsolata", 8, FontStyle.Bold),
        new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(250, 190, 500, 500),
        new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap));

        part3.DrawString(bunifuTextBox3.Text,
        new System.Drawing.Font("Inconsolata", 8, FontStyle.Bold),
        new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(250, 235, 500, 500),
        new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap));

        part3.DrawString(bunifuTextBox4.Text,
        new System.Drawing.Font("Inconsolata", 8, FontStyle.Bold),
        new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(250, 280, 500, 500),
        new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap));

        //a.Save(@"C:\Users\khadj\Desktop\rea (2)\rea1\Testштрихкод1.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        pictureBox2.Image = a;

    }
```

[image: Происходит следующее если не перезагружать программу]

Comment: Это что, winforms?

Comment: Да, это WinForms

Comment: @aepot вы по типу `System.Drawing.Graphics` не догадались?) (4 строчка)

Comment: @return эту библиотеку из нугета можно в любой тип проекта установить. Я спросил автора, потому что он не указал тег.

Comment: Господа, можете ли мне помочь? Сказав ответ решении, мне это очень нужно!

Comment: Самый главный ответ - это "изучите разницу между ссылочными и значимыми типами". Узнайте, что такое ссылка на объект. `Image a = pictureBox1.Image` получает ссылку на текущую картинку в боксе. Странно, что вы это не заметили, научитесь замечать.

Comment: Еще `part1`, `part2`, `part3`, `part4` - это один и тот же объект. `Graphics` - это ссылка на инструмент для рисования на картинке. Если у битмапа 100 раз запросить ссылку на `Graphics`, то она 100 раз вернет одну и ту же ссылку. Еще вы шрифт, кисть и формат строки создаете 4 раза, можно это делать 1 раз и сохранить в 3 переменные. У вас только прямоугольники разные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

приблизительно так:

```
Image a = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image.Size);
// ваш код
pictureBox2.Image = a;
```

Т.е. мы создаем новый рисунок идентичного размера и присваиваем его в отрисовку на pictureBox.